# Click event delegation disappears when opening element in jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

if I create a button, add a click handler to it and then insert it into the DOM as follows:

```
var modalContainer = $('<div id="modalContainer" style="display:none;" />')
modalContainer.append($('<input type="button" id="someButton" />'));
this_.template = modalContainer;
$( this_.template ).delegate( ":button", "click", function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
$('#someElement").after(this_.template);
```

At this point if I run $("#someButton").click(), the click event fires. However, as soon as I call $( "#modalContainer" ).dialog(); and open it, the click event no longer fires.

I assume that in the process of repositioning the elements in the DOM as part of the Dialog open process the events are being removed? Is this correct?if so what is the best way to get round this? I can add the delegation after the dialog has been opened, but I then have to worry about removing it or checking the click event exists before adding it each time on Open.

I am having to use an older version of jQuery (1.4.1) so do not have the on method and have been warned off using live for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
  alert("clicked");
  });
```

**Edit**

```
$("body").delegate("button", "click", function(){
  alert("clicked");
```

});

Comment: See above. I don't have access to the on method

Comment: how about $(document).delegate("button", "click", function()

Comment: I see. So is it because I am delegating the event to the container , which is not being repositioned in the DOM as part of the dialog open process and so the click event can't bubble up to it? If I gave the button a parent container within the main dialog container and delehated the event to that I guess that would also work?

Comment: while delegating an element, master element should be there in the dom

Comment: The master element is there in the DOM still, but dialog open moves the child elements outside of it, so the event cannot bubble up through the DOM to it. I'm guessing this is what is happening, but will confirm later and mark as answered if that is the case.

Comment: In your case, modalContainer is not appended to the dom at the time of delegation

Comment: So why is it that the event fires after I append it to the DOM, but only stops when I open the element as a dialog?

Comment: Your answer worked, but I not for the reasons you have suggested. It was as i thought that the event was firing, but not being caught by the element it had been delegated to as the dialog open process removes its child elements and reinserts them higher up the DOM, so the event never bubbles to the container. Your answer works because it delegates the event handling to the body, but instead of using that I added an inner div container and delegated it to that. The results were the same, but the event doesbnt have to bubble up all the way to body.